# JointJs Link hides after Zoom In

Tags: jointjs

I am referring to `joint/demo/shapes/html.html`. I need to scroll the diagram when using zoom in for HtmlElement. To do this I used `overflow: auto;` in html.js. The Link gets disappeared when it crosses the boundary. Please see the [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgMoC.png).

To reproduce this issue you can do the following changes.

In https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/fe1c39eda24afb2432c4306c1a47c4b79d6039b1/demo/shapes/html.html

at line 19 change `'overflow: hidden;`' to `'overflow: auto;`'

and In https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/fe1c39eda24afb2432c4306c1a47c4b79d6039b1/demo/shapes/src/html.js

at line 134 change y value to 350 `'position: { x: 350, y: 350 }`'

Could you please let me know how can I fix this?

Comment: @roman and Jointjs team, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please, try to apply the following CSS `.joint-paper > svg { overflow: visible; }`. Or enlarge the paper when an element crosses the paper boundary.

Comment: @Roman Thanks a lot. This worked like a charm.